# Is it normal to say "reply distantly" or "reply in a distant voice"?

Tags: meaning

In my language (which is not English), it is normal to write: "reply distantly" , "speak distantly", "reply in a distant voice".

"Distant" here means strange, emotionless, cold

I wonders if it is the same in English. I feel a little odd because I have never seen anyone write like that before.

Comment: It's not a common idiom.  It might be a bit more idiomatic to say something like "He replied with a distant voice."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A readily-understood trope in English. Here's a good example from *[The American Civil War of 2018](https://books.google.com/books?id=PhQxSAlGU5YC&pg=PA152&dq=%22replied%20distantly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCGoVChMI0dn3tIzayAIVQm8-Ch21pwp2#v=onepage&q=%22replied%20distantly%22&f=false)* by B Larson:

> It's been a long time since I've been there,” Ashley **replied
>   distantly**, as if remembering a long-suppressed memory.
>           “You have been around this area a lot, haven't you?” Michael asked, noticing the
>   **distant** look in her eyes.
>           “You could say that...." Ashley said lowly.

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvote, a curse on this site.

Comment: I gave you an up, since I referenced your example in my own answer as being correct... seems only right.

Comment: @SkJohnson Thank you.  You are a gentleman (or gentlewoman) and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

Distant isn't usually used in that manner with the way you've worded it (people would likely interpret it to mean that the reply came from someone who was physically far away, rather than emotionally detached); However, if worded the way Ashley has stated then the meaning you are asking about will be understood.

An alternative might be to say "they replied listlessly" or "they gave a robotic   response"

Comment: *Normal* (the OP's word) or *usual* (yours) isn't really apt.  *Readily understood* is the better measure.  *Distant* in the sense of cool and aloof has a history in English going back over 300 years.  Neither *listless* nor *robotic* are synonyms.

Comment: I don't see how cool or aloof have the same connotation as strange or devoid of emotion.

Comment: *Strange* I'd have to agree with.  Temperature is commonly used as metaphoric measure of emotion.

Comment: I guess I just take cool to mean not easily bothered or evenly tempered, which I view as an emotion, itself, rather than taking it to mean empty or no emotion. But it is fine line, to say the least.

Comment: Your comment moved me to consult the *OED*.  Meaning 4 is "not heated by passion or emotion" and "calm."  (And, good Lord! goes back to *Beowulf*!)  5b is "wanting in cordiality."  So I think the overall connotation is withholding emotion when it might be expected.

Comment: Ah, the definition of 5b throws a slightly different light on it, for me. Applying that meaning here, then you're right, "robotic" is not a feasible alternative. I'd still argue that "listlessly" implies a similar connotation, though.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the use of an adverb which almost always brings attention to itself and acts like a speed bump, its likely better to say “he said in a distant voice” and maybe add a showing phrase after to reinforce the characters distant mindset.

Comment: Hello, 286. While what you say may well be correct (in fact Hot Licks said much the same 4 years ago), for an answer to be considered of a good standard on ELU it should be accompanied by linked and attributed supporting evidence. Answers lacking such come across as (and may well be) mere opinion.

Comment: Indeed an opinion- if fact writing is art not science and in art one should go with what sounds best and the best writers follow this path.

Comment: But usage _is_ a (softish) science, being analysable and codifiable (though having grey areas and shifting goalposts). And ELU expects evidence showing reasonably common use / acceptance of usages in answers. For what sounds the most appealing (largely subjective, of course) WritersSE and other sites, rather than ELU,  are the correct places to frequent.